# A WPF ItemsControl and WrapPanel walk into a bar

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, itemscontrol, wrappanel

I have a `ItemsControl` that displays a bunch of `UserControl`'s inside of a `WrapPanel`. This works perfectly, unless I have a bunch of UserControls, and then the overflow is rendered off screen, and I can't access it. My goal is to have the WrapPanel wrap horizontally, but once the controls are off the screen, to present a scroll bar, and this seems to not work for me.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <local:ServerControl DataContext="{Binding }" /> <!-- The actual UserControl -->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

When the application first starts, this is what it looks like. What you can't see if that there should be 14 boxes viewed. The WrapPanel is doing its job, but it's rendered outside of the bounds of the window.

[image: User Controls off the screen]

This shows all the UserControls, but I had to expand the window to be able to see them all.

[image: Expanded window to see all controls, rather than a scrollbar]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ServerMonitor.Wpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ServerMonitor.Wpf"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:ServerMonitor.Wpf.Models"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Leading Hedge Server Monitor" Height="350" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <models:MainWindowViewModel>
            <models:MainWindowViewModel.MachineNames>
                <!-- Test Servers -->
                <System:String>T009</System:String>
                <System:String>T010</System:String>
                <System:String>T011</System:String>
                <System:String>T012</System:String>
            </models:MainWindowViewModel.MachineNames>
        </models:MainWindowViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">

        </Menu>

        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                        <local:ServerControl DataContext="{Binding }" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what actual behaviour you are expecting - perhaps you could detail exactly what you want? If you put the wrap panel inside a scroll viewer then it will not work as a wrap panel anymore because the scroll viewer has infinite dimensions. In which case you might as well just use a stack panel. Again, tell me what you want and I can possibly give you some ideas/advice. :)

Comment: Sorry, the goal is to have the controls wrap like a wrap panel, but if the controls wrap outside the bounds of the window itself, to activate a scroll bar so I don't need to resize the whole window itself to see everything.

Comment: So, you want to wrap horizontally, but when it reaches the bottom you want to scroll vertically?

Comment: Correct! That's is what I'm trying to accomplish. My frustration is putting a damper on my vocabulary, apparently. :)

Comment: In that case I think the second half of Moises' answer is what you want.

Comment: I've already tried both of his suggestions, and neither works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you second row height to `*`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <-- This is what you want -->
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Setting a `RowDefinition` to `Auto` means it will calculate the cumulative `DesiredHeight` of all child elements in that row and assign it to the `Height` property of `RowDefinition`. So, as your `WrapPanel` grows, it will apply the height to that row and stretch out your parent `Grid`.

Comment: I still think cleaner would be to put the scroll viewer outside the grid and leave the row as auto - but whatever floats your boat

Comment: You need the ScrollViewer too.

Answer (score 8):

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <local:ServerControl DataContext="{Binding }" /> <!-- The actual UserControl -->
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

OR

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=OneWay}">
     ...
  <ItemsControl/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: @DanChampagne The first part of this answer doesn't make sense, but the second part should work. Try remove your local:ServerControl and give the Border a fixed width & height. It really should work - I've copied and pasted your code, commented out the ServerControl, put in the ScrollViewer and it does work...

Comment: @user3690202 I added a couple prints to the post to show what I'm seeing. Neither of these suggestions actually give me the behavior I'm after. Both require me to expand the window, rather than giving me a userable ScrollBar.

Comment: This is the problem: <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />